# how to center the contents of a <div> tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i try to bring these cards to center , the codes link is this :

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/pm76o3ve
```

and here is the image of my cards that are in a div
[image]

Comment: Paste the code of the fiddle in the question itself, links are susceptible of getting broken or lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the cards `inline-block`, remove the `float` and add `text-align: center;` to the parent.

```css
.samples-panel {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none!important; /* had to add !important to overwrite bootstrap */
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.cardtext {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="samples-panel text-center">
    <a href="#"><h1>samples</h1></a>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Or use flexbox on the parent, assign `flex-wrap: wrap;` to allow the cards to wrap, and apply `justify-content: center;` to center the cards.

```css
.samples-panel {
    background-color: #fff;
    
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
 }

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: none;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.cardtext {
    padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="samples-panel text-center">
    <a href="#"><h1>samples</h1></a>
    <div class="cards">
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/7c689b96e97042b295cbbcb8607962a5.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
        <div class="cardtext">
            <div class="cardtext">
                <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Interior Designer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @MiladM oops, there was a specificity issue in my first example. Updated my answer. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: @dippas what isn't what OP wants?

Comment: @MichaelCoker your first snippet which you already changed ;)